# add/remove class on a div if an element contains a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div built like this:

```
<div class="navigation fixed-top">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

When I'm clicking on `About` it automatically adds `class="active"`. For example when `href="#home"` d contain `class="active"` I want to change `<div class="navigation navigation-fixed-top">`  into `<div class="navigation navigation-fixed-bottom">`.

I'm trying this:

```
if($('a[href="#home"]').hasClass('active')) 
{ $(".navigation").toggleClass("fixed-bottom fixed-top"); }
```

And the output is looking like this: `class="navigation navigation-fixed-top fixed-bottom fixed-top"`
It seem that is just adding those classes.

Comment: `.not()` returns a jQuery object. Use `.is(".active") === false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
var isActive = $('a[href="#home"]').hasClass('active');
$(".navigation")
  .toggleClass("navigation-fixed-bottom", isActive)
  .toggleClass("navigation-fixed-top", !isActive);
```

Comment: just tried this and it adds `fixed-bottom` after the `fixed-top` the output is looking like this `navigation navigation-fixed-top fixed-bottom` and it should look like `navigation navigation-fixed-bottom`

Comment: I've edited my answer. `navigation`, `fixed-bottom` and `navigation-fixed-bottom` are distinct, and completely unrelated classes. You can't toggle them partially, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Now I get `getSyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: Oops, there was an extra semicolon.

Comment: Now is partially working, it toggles fixed-bottom when `a[href="#home"]` has a class of active but when that is not active anymore it doesn't switch back to fixed-top. I forgot to mention that this is happening in the same page there is no refresh of the page when the active class is changing

Comment: Then you need to run this snippet, each time the class changes.

Comment: And how can I do this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48388/discussion-between-sabof-and-alecs)

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the navigation class easily by using [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with multiple classes:

```
$(".navigation").toggleClass("fixed-bottom fixed-top");
```

Assuming that the div only has one of those classes, this code will remove it and add the other one. Running it again will restore the original state, and so on.

Comment: I've just tried but it seems that is adding this classes is not doing anything else. I've edited my question, please take a look...

Comment: more exactly the output is looking like this `navigation navigation-fixed-top fixed-bottom` and it should look like this `navigation navigation-fixed-bottom`

Comment: @Alecs: Well, which classes are you using *exactly*? You wrote `fixed-top` in the question, did you mean `navigation-fixed-top`?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the markup, by default I have fixed-top and I want to change it fixed-bottom when that href has an active class and when it doesn't have to switch it back to fixed-top. I forgot to mention that in my page is no refresh involved when the active class is switching.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed you something in JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/hawugefi/2/edit

```
$(function(){
  if($('a[href="#home"]').is('.active')) {
    $(".navigation").toggleClass("fixed-bottom fixed-top"); 
  }

  console.log($(".navigation").attr('class'))
});
```

To toggle between two classes, you can use `$.toggle('class1 class2')`, as @Jon mentioned.

Comment: This seems to be good but I don't need the `click` function I need just to add that the `fixed-bottom` class only if that `a` element has  that specific attribute and is active, if not do the opposite